# Z-Index not working while using -webkit-rotate

Tags: html, css, webkit, z-index

This code is working correctly with the border rotating on top of logo image but if I change the z-index of border to 9988 and of image to 9999 the code is not working. What am I missing? I want the border to rotate behind of image

Thanks

```css
#logo-position {width: 170px; height: 170px; position: absolute; }
  #mylogo     { width: 170px; height: 170px; position: absolute;}
  #mylogo img {position: absolute;}
  .logoborder {z-index:9999;} 
  .logotext {z-index:9988;}
  .logoborder:hover { -moz-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
       -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
       -ms-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes rotate {  
   from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
   to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
   from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
   to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }
  @-ms-keyframes rotate {
   from {-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
   to {-ms-transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }
   @-o-keyframes rotate {
   from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
   to {-o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
   }
```

```html
<body> 
  <div id="logo-position">
   <div id="mylogo">
    <a href="http://www.makepassive.com">
 
     <img class="logoborder" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhC7Z.png" alt="logo_170x170_300px-border" width="170" height="170"/>
     <img class="logotext" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiyVY.png" alt="logo_170x170_300px-text" width="170" height="170"/>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: A demo with the actual images would be useful here.

Comment: Here, I am working on this website [link]http://www.makepassive.com/[link]

Comment: Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Hi, I have added the Example to the Question.Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you change `z-index` of `.logotext` to 9999, and `.logoborder` to 9988, you are basically hiding your border element behind the image. Although your picture is a PNG file with transparent background, but it will stack up in front of `.logoborder`. As a result, you will never be able to find it by mouse pointer. I created a [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/ZQqdxj?editors=1100) example of your code and added `border: 5px solid black;` to `.logotext` to show the issue.

To solve,  you need to put `.logotext` before `.logoborder`, like this:

```
<img class="logotext" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiyVY.png" alt="logo_170x170_300px-text" width="170" height="170"/>
<img class="logoborder" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhC7Z.png" alt="logo_170x170_300px-border" width="170" height="170"/>
```

Then, you change your CSS code like this:

```
.logotext:hover + .logoborder{ -moz-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}
```

Then it will work as you like.

Comment: Again when I changed the code in the website its not functioning there while its functioning on my pc.

Comment: HI .Finally solved. Needed to clear the cache in wordpress

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept my answer as the official answer to your question please.